# How to make a db query when a date has passed

Tags: symfony

I made an application with Symfony 6.
I have a reservation entity with startDate, endDate and state_id fields.

I would like to automatically change the state_id field (to a certain id) when the startDate field corresponding to DateTime('now').

I don't know how to do this without visiting a page but instead in background.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Depending on the OS your platform is running on, take a look at schedulers like [cronjob](https://www.hivelocity.net/kb/what-is-cron-job/). Run symfony commands scheduled that update your entities. [Here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/the-fast-track/en/24-cron.html) is some information from the symfony docs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My application is hosted by hostinger.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement **Doctrine Events** on `state_id` field. Whenever `state_id` field value change you can persist any value in Entity so you can set `startDate` or `endDate` in your case.

This is the documentation [link](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/events.html)

Please use `postPersist` or `postUpdate` event on `state_id`

Answer (score 0):

So, I made a cron job in my server to launch a command that I created in symfony with

```
php bin/console make:command
```

with all the logic inside.

And it works perfectly !